How to configure Remote ordering with iPad and micros res 3700 api?
Ok so it's not really a problem but It worked really well and I want it back.  About 3 years ago someone smart person got this to work for me.  I opened a browser, typed the address, logged in and next thing I had a micros terminal on my iPad.  I was at my house I made a small order hit send and 1 minute later I was getting a call from my restaurant asking if the ticket was mine that just printed.
It had something todo with making a new terminal and calling it server api.  Now this was done for me in like 30 mins.  Long story short I had to disable it because I didn't want that active if we weren't using them.  How can I get this awesome option back?

There's not enough information here for us to comment. Perhaps you should talk to the 'smart person's who set it up originally. It does look like some sort of hack into the restaurant system, though, which raise questions about the legality of the process.
